# How to recover Kali linux password using LILO?

Tags: linux, bash, passwords, kali-linux, lilo

I forgot my Kali password and I tried getting into LILO single user mode but it still asks for root password (which I forgot). As a secondary measure I just ran

```
init=/bin/bash
```

The command runs but then it gets stuck when booting the system, I repeated this about 3 times but it still gets stuck in the exam exact place as last time (it gets stuck in a place where the prompt is just checking all my system specifications) so I guess this is some kind of security measure for Kali.

I don't know if I'm wrong.
Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same exact problem

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow for systems using LILO bootloader

## Step 1

At LILO bootloader type `linux single` and press the ENTER key:

```
Boot: linux single
```

## Step 2

When presented with the command prompt, issue the `passwd` command.

```
passwd
```

## Step 3

Before rebooting the system, it is a good idea to run the `sync` command.

```
sync
```

## Step 4

Reboot.

You should now be able to login into the system with your new root password.

[This website](http://www.linuxlookup.com/howto/recover_root_password_linux_systems) explains how to recover grub passwords as well.

Comment: I can use the Linux single command since it still asks my original root password